# Do Java scheduled tasks run on all EC2 instances of AWS auto scaling group?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a Java web app which runs in Tomcat within an auto-scaling group of EC2s which are provisioned by Elastic Beanstalk.  My web app has a scheduled task that runs every night to clear records from the database which is in RDS.

My question is - If my auto-scaling group is scaled up to, say, 4 instances, will there be 4 different threads executing the scheduled task and running queries on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Auto scaling group deploys your webapp to all 4 instances to make it same as your original instance. Which means, your "scheduled task" also runs on 4 instances and does whatever it is coded for.